# Help with "System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0"

Tags: apex

Getting "System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0" even though I am checking if the list is empty or not. Any ideas?

```
trigger ABTestingAutonumber on Account(before insert, before update) {
    list < Account > a = [SELECT Id, AB_Testing_Autonumber__c FROM Account WHERE AB_Testing_Autonumber__c != null ORDER BY AB_Testing_Autonumber__c DESC LIMIT 1];
    Decimal maxlead = a[0].AB_Testing_Autonumber__c;
    if (a.size()>0) {
        for (Account a2: Trigger.new) {
            if (a2.OwnerId == '00537000000Qsqj') {
                a2.AB_Testing_Autonumber__c = Integer.valueOf(maxlead) + 1;
            } else {
                a2.AB_Testing_Autonumber__c = 1;                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Decimal maxlead = a[0].AB_Testing_Autonumber__c;` will fail if no records are returned

Comment: You are checking the size of a after making a[0] and it will fail if no records returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be inside `if(a.size()>0)`. For a empty list a[0] will throw exception.

> Decimal maxlead = a[0].AB_Testing_Autonumber__c;

Change the logic to:

```
trigger ABTestingAutonumber on Account(before insert, before update) {
    list < Account > a = [SELECT Id, AB_Testing_Autonumber__c FROM Account WHERE AB_Testing_Autonumber__c != null ORDER BY AB_Testing_Autonumber__c DESC LIMIT 1];
    if (a.size()>0) {
        Decimal maxlead = a[0].AB_Testing_Autonumber__c;
        for (Account a2: Trigger.new) {
            if (a2.OwnerId == '00537000000Qsqj') {
                a2.AB_Testing_Autonumber__c = Integer.valueOf(maxlead) + 1;
            } else {
                a2.AB_Testing_Autonumber__c = 1;                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```